# Disney Infinity 2.0 - Where is all the story content?

Tags: disney-infinity-2.0

I picked up Disney Infinity 2.0 for WiiU at a steep discount, and it just has Merida and her story token.  I'm able to play her story line, but not interested in the toy box mode.  I picked up a stack of tokens at a second hand store that just change colors and add toybox features, so those are sitting on the shelf.

The Marvel Infinity 2.0 characters I purchased won't work in Merida's world.  So I guess I need to pick up some Marvel tokens too.

Here's the short question:
I'm interested in the story progression.  What stories should I seek out in Infinity 2.0, and what additional pieces do I need to purchase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're interested in story progression, then you're looking specifically for "play set" pieces.  These are usually tall bits of clear plastic and fit in the sort of hexagonal slot on the pad.

The play sets are listed on [this Disney page](https://infinity.disney.com/play-sets/marvel).  If you have the Infinity 2.0 game disc, then you can use Infinity 2.0 play sets only.  Infinity 3.0 stuff (power discs, characters, etc) won't work with the 2.0 edition, and 1.0's play sets don't carry forward, although the other items do.

This is kind of confusing, so you might check the FAQs on [this page](https://infinity.disney.com/compatibility) for all the details.

As you've noticed, you also need characters that go with each play set - characters from other play sets can't be used together, except in Toy Box mode.

If you've got mostly Marvel characters, you probably want the Marvel play sets.  There is "The Avengers," "Spider-Man," and "Guardians of the Galaxy."  The characters are all mutually exclusive, so you'll need at least one character from each set to play.  For instance, Hulk only works in "The Avengers," Nick Fury only works in "Spider-Man," and Groot only works in "Guardians of the Galaxy."

Comment: Is there other game content around the sandbox, or just those "play sets"?  I guess I was expecting something like Skylanders

Comment: @Baronz, you can download sandboxes that other people have created, or create your own objectives/levels/whatever, but most of the story content you'll find is from the play sets.